# How to make triangle with '&' and '+' symbol in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to make a pyramid like this one in javascript?

```
   &
  +++
 &&&&&
+++++++
```

I've tried this one but didn't get the exact output.

```js
function pyramid(n) {

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let str = ' '.repeat(n - i);
    let symb1 = '&'.repeat(i * 2 - 1);
    let symb2 = '+'.repeat(i * 2 - 1);
    console.log(str + symb1 + str);
    console.log(str + symb2 + str);
  }
}
pyramid(4)
```

Comment: Please look at the tags you use on your questions. The [pyramid] tag is about a Python web framework, not the shape. We don't make tags about shapes because it doesn't help categorize questions. See [What are tags, and how should I use them?](/help/tagging)

Comment: What is `n`?  Why are there two closing curly braces?  Have you checked the browser's development console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

- Declare a variable `res` which gonna store in it, lines.
- loop over number of lines and in each one switch between two symbols by using [*modulo*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) `%`

```js
function pyramid(n) {
  let res = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let str = ' '.repeat(n - i);
    let line = ['+', '&'][i % 2].repeat(i * 2 - 1);
    res += str + line + "\n";
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(pyramid(4));
```

**Note:** `\n` character for a line break to add a new line into `res`ult string.

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting *both* lines on every iteration of the loop:

```
let symb1 = '&'.repeat(i * 2 - 1);
let symb2 = '+'.repeat(i * 2 - 1);
console.log(str + symb1 + str);
console.log(str + symb2 + str);
```

Instead, *conditionally output* one or the other.  You can check whether `i` is even or odd for the condition:

```
if (i % 2 == 1) {
  let symb1 = '&'.repeat(i * 2 - 1);
  console.log(str + symb1 + str);
} else {
  let symb2 = '+'.repeat(i * 2 - 1);
  console.log(str + symb2 + str);
}
```

(You can of course refactor this into something shorter, reduce repetition, etc.  The point here is to demonstrate the goal of outputting *one or the other* instead of *both*.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and test for even using [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

You can push into an array and join with newlines

```js
function pyramid(n) { 
  const lines = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let str = ' '.repeat(n - i);
    let symb = (i%2===0 ? '+' : '&').repeat(i * 2 - 1);
    lines.push(str + symb + str);
  }
  console.log(lines.join("\n"));
}
pyramid(4)
```